# Can the Government step in, to ban bitcoins?

Tags: government

The price of bitcoins increase with demand. Demand increases because people can spend the bitcoins. I think the price of bitcoins started as a drug money. The main advantage of bitcoins is that the sender or buyer is anonymous.
However that does not cause the increase in demand to what it is now.
I believe the current demand is increasing as more people are accepting bitcoins, and seeing this, more people are buying it.

If the government makes bitcoins illegal, people would loose trust in the bitcoins and the prices will go down.
Cant this cause the prices to go down?

Comment: "The price of bitcoins started as a drug money. The main advantage of bitcoins is that the sender or buyer is anonymous." - citation needed

Comment: Please define "the Government", because last time I checked there was not one for the whole world and there are a few countries where Bitcoin is similarly big or even bigger than in the US.

Answer (score 2):

I think that banning bitcoins and enforcing the ban would be a huge endeavor. It would be expensive and probably politically unpopular. See this question: [How much would it cost for a government to undermine Bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4998/how-much-would-it-cost-for-a-government-to-undermine-bitcoins?rq=1) Also see [What methods could a government use to shutdown Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/366/what-methods-could-a-government-use-to-shutdown-bitcoin?lq=1)